# Option to not add line breaks in no-op (empty) functions in JavaScript (IntelliJ Web/PHP storm)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm

I can not for the life of me find a formatter option to turn off automatic line breaks inside no-op function braces. The line breaks are added automatically for both arrow functions and regular functions. This is frustrating when for example passing no op functions to other functions (as a hook or callback), i.e. `wrapWithCommonErrors(() => {})`.

`function() {}` 
becomes
`function() {
}`

`() => {}` 
becomes
`() => {
}`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried the `Simple blocks in one line` option?

You can find it at

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Code Style` -> `JavaScript` -> `Wrapping and Braces` -> `Keep when reformatting`